# try catch fails on very simple try

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to get an API call working.

Following code is activated on the server.

```
Meteor.methods({
  "gap-api": function() {

  this.unblock();
  var response = Meteor.wrapasync(apiCall)();

  return response;
  }
});
```

1. the gap-api meteor method is used to get the data in a session variable on the client. > this works
2. next I want to get the data from the api call in the meteor method gap-api. > this does not work.

The error I am getting is internal server error 500. So the try fails but I do not understand why.

Before I implement the actual API I first want to get the "this is a try return" string working.

Any Advice?

Thanks

```
var apiCall = function(callback) {
  try {

   var response = "this is a try return";
   callback(null, response);
  } catch (error) {
    // If the API responded with an error message and a payload
    if (error.response) {
      var errorCode = error.response.data.code;
      var errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
      // Otherwise use a generic error message
    } else {
      var errorCode = 500;
      var errorMessage = "Cannot access the API";
    }
    // Create an Error object and return it via callback
    var myError = new Meteor.Error(errorCode, errorMessage);
    callback(myError, null);
  }
};
```

I am using this code as a reference:
https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-external-apis-your

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it should be `Meteor.wrapAsync`, not `Meteor.wrapasync`.

Second, your `apiCall` function expects `callback` parameter, but you're calling it without any.

Your `apiCall` function should not expect `callback` parameter, it should just either `return` or throw exception. You're wrapping it in sync method call, after all.